# Three JS add/remove a event in mousedown

Tags: three.js

In three JavaSript, I have to remove the event once I clicked on a cube and dragged i to another cube. Say, my concern is once I click on the cube and drag my mouse pointer it create a line where when I click on the another cue the line draws continuously without staying at the particular cube . Check the comment for fiddle url.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/okzg4u05/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/okzg4u05/2/ like that?

Comment: @Roy my concern is once I click on the cube and drag my mouse pointer it create a line where when I click on the another cue the line draws continuously without staying at the particular cube

Comment: Control the click with a flag, if click cube flag(true), so if you click again in another cube and flag(true) trigger another event.

Comment: yes @Roy.
Got the solution..thanks

Comment: @Roy How can we draw multiple lines between the cubes..?

Comment: Yes, redraw changing +- X and Y